# How are large print (20x30) photos captured?

Tags: portrait, large-format

I've just noticed that formats like 20" by 30" have peculiar dimensions and large pixel sizes. How are these achieved? Does the photographer stitch multiple full-res photos?

If so, is there a panning tool that he uses, like one would in multiple focus stacks with macro?

Comment: 20x30 is the same format as 35mm film and full frame sensor digital cameras. I wouldn't exactly call the 1.5:1 format *peculiar*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Professional photographers sometimes use higher-resolution cameras with 40 or 60 MPixels (typical DSRLs, even professional full-frame, have just above 20 MPixel).
2. Another option is surely stitching; there is a multitude of software that does a good job, for example LightRoom, a professional standard tool, does it fully automatically.
3. You can artificially increas pixel count with software (instead of just getting larger identically colored pixels clusters, it interpolates cleverly); and then manually work specific critical areas in Photoshop or similar tools.

Either one results in large enough resolutions to print great looking 20x30 inches.

Generally, for high-quality (art-show level) prints, you should have 300 or more pixels per inch, but 150 pixels per inch gives nice prints for home use.

300 pixels per inch for 20x30 inch would need 6000 by 9000 pixel (54 MPixel); 
150 pixels per inch would need only 13.5 MPixel.

I have several prints in 20 x 30 made from 22 MPixel shots and they look great (that's about 182 dpi). 20x30 is not a good format though, because frames/glasses are unproportionally expensive and hard to get for that size - check into matching frames/glasses *before* you order prints.

Comment: Thanks! For stitching images I was more curious about the hardware, I'm aware of the software options. 
I'm not purchasing once, was just baffled by the size of the image, but foolish me forgot to account for professional cameras.

Comment: There are rails systems that can be used for moving the camera defined distances between shots, but that is an elaborate setup that you can't really carry around. It would be used in museums for example, to take high-res stitch-shots from the Mona Lisa and such. I don't know details, though.

Comment: Where can you get prints on real photo paper with 600 or 1200 DPI?

Comment: @jarnbjo , you are right. I didn't verify the max supported resolution, I just assumed that number, because most laser printers do 1200. (I always sent them the highest I had, without calculating the dpi). I'll adjust the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes they are stitched. Sometimes they are made with 35mm full frame sensor DSLRs with high resolution. Currently NIkon sells a 36MP FF DSLR and Canon sells a 50MP DSLR. Sometimes even larger, medium format cameras are used. These cameras may be very high resolution digital cameras in the 50-100MP range or they may be film cameras using very high quality low speed film that is then used to make large prints the traditional way or by scanning the negative/positive using very high resolution scanners to produce digital images.